# Eraser equivalent for a drawing app, c#, silverlight, wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, line

I'm working on a simple drawing app to further advance my skills and I can't seem to get the logic down for an eraser tool. The app simply uses the Line class to create lines as the user moves their finger. For the eraser tool I tried using the VisualTreeHelper as follows:

```
List<UIElement> elements = (List<UIElement>)VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(e.GetPosition(tree), ContentPanelCanvas);

            foreach (UIElement element in elements)
            {
                if (element is Line)
                {
                    this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Remove(element);
                }
            }
```

It at some points but can be very slow and laggy. Sometimes I would have to touch the area more than 5 times to get rid of the line there.

Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: is it slow and laggy, or is your hit testing missing?  does visualtreehelper look for an exact pixel (1x1) or does it support an area?  your finger press is a lot bigger than one pixel...

Comment: I just read a tutorial on the VisualTreeHelper before making this app so I'm pretty new to it. I believe it is supporting the area of the finger not exact pixels, I don't know how to do this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `e.GetPosition(tree)` will be returning a point.  Try instead using a `Rect` with the position as its center.

```
const double fingerMargin = 10.0;

Point p = e.GetPosition(tree);
Rect r = new Rect(p.X - fingerMargin, p.Y - fingerMargin, fingerMargin * 2, fingerMargin * 2); 

var elements = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(r, ContentPanelCanvas);

Line lineToRemove = elements.OfType<Line>().FirstOrDefault();
if (lineToRemove != null)
{
    ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Remove(lineToRemove);
}
```

Note don't cast the result of FindElementsInHostCoordinates to `List<T>`, that is an implementation detail, the documentation only guarantees it to be an `IEnumerable<UIElement>`, besides which it is an unnecessary cast.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually looking for the set of elements that match the hit test of a single pixel.  If your lines are narrow, then it's like a needle in a haystack; it's very hard to hit the line precisely to remove it.

Instead you need to use a fuzzy match using a rectangle instead of a point.  You can use the same API, just the rectangle version of it:

- [VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates Method (Rect, UIElement)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838303%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(r, MainCanvas);
Is not returning any Elements.